# Возможно ли подключить уже скомпилированный проект GO к другом проекту и вызывать от туда функции скомпилированного проекта

Tags: golang, компиляция

(linux) Здравствуйте, возможно ли подключить уже скомпилированный проект GO к своему проекту, чтобы я мог вызывать функции скомпилированного проекта в своем проекте?
Альтернатива dlopen в c++

Comment: если бинарник экспортирует нужные функции, то все возможно.

Answer (score 1):

В си или в го? В си можно, если проект скомпилирован
с `--buildmode=c-shared`. В го можно через механизм
[плагинов](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/). Документация для
сишного варианта:

```
$ go help buildmode
```

```
The 'go build' and 'go install' commands take a -buildmode argument which
indicates which kind of object file is to be built. Currently supported values
are:

[…]

        -buildmode=c-shared
                Build the listed main package, plus all packages it imports,
                into a C shared library. The only callable symbols will
                be those functions exported using a cgo //export comment.
                Requires exactly one main package to be listed.

[…]
```

Пример сишного варианта:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

import "C"

//export goMain
func goMain() {
        fmt.Println("Hello from Go!")
}

func main() {}
```

```
#include "gomain.h"

int main(void)
{
        goMain();

        return 0;
}
```

```
$ go build --buildmode c-shared -o ./libgomain.so ./main.go
```

```
$ gcc -L . -o ./main.bin ./main.c -l gomain
```

```
$ env LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$PWD" ./main.bin
```

Если нужен вариант гошного плагина, тоже можно добавить.

Comment: Спасибо за понятный ответ!